# Solaris ZFS ACLs

Tags: unix, solaris, zfs

I want to reset the ACLs on a directory tree so that the root directory ACL replaces the ACLs on all files and folders below it. How best can I achieve this?

*Edit: Is this question poorly worded? Can someone give me some feedback even if you don't know the answer?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find out the ACL by running an `ls -V` on the directory (in this example, I'm running it on the `root` directory from `/`:

```
drwx------   4 root     root          10 Feb 25  2011 root
             owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow
             group@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
          everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

You can then run a `chmod -R A=<<INSERT ACL HERE>>  *` on the directory, where `<<INSERT ACL HERE>>` is replaced with the acl as listed in the `ls` command.

In this case, I'd `cd root` and then issue `chmod -R A=owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow\ group@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow\ everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow *`

This usually works for me.

Comment: ah cool, that makes sense, so simple. There should be nothing wrong with setting the 'r' and 'd' inherit flags on with this operation?

Comment: I shouldn't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, you might want to consider to assign different permissions to Dir and Files, for instance 2755 and 0644, in this case

```
$ cd 

$ find . -t d -exec chmod 2755 {} \; # update ACL on dirs

$ find . -t f -exec chmod 0644 {} \; # update ACL on files
```

OB